# Undefined reference to pointer to a function

Tags: c, dll, linker, function-pointers

I'm new to this topic. I'm trying to dynamically link a shared library in my c code, but I'm getting an error...

```
undefined reference to `func'
```

I've searched the web and I can't find anything wrong with my syntax...

```
void *handle;
int (*func)(char **);
handle = dlopen(argv[0], RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);
*(int **)&func = dlsym(handle, pluggin_method->FunctionName); //I might need to pass a string by first using strcpy
int func_ret_val = (func)(argv); //execute function
```

I'm banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out. Any help?

Comment: Where is the implementation of `func`?

Comment: Are you sure you know what you are doing? Please provide a [mcve] and state what you want to accomplish..

Comment: the implementation of func varies from different shared libraries. I'm building a shell that allows the user to load new pluggins

Comment: The syntax seems to be correct; you're creating a function pointer and later assigning to it (the cast is terribly ugly though). I think your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure `dlopen` succeeded? Are you sure the function name is adequate? `dlsym` succeeded? (minor: Why do you cast `func` like this???)

Comment: In which file `func` is defined and in which file it is being used? Are they different?

Comment: check out... http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/index.html

Comment: @Pawan the function is not defined because the code is supposed to except a range of shared libraries -- so theres definitely a problem here in that how am I supposed to know that parameters for said functions?

Comment: Casting is usually done "the other way": `func = (int (*)(char**)) dlsym(...);`.

Comment: @molbdnilo now I get this error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: ...and its pointing toward the assignment operator

Comment: regarding this line: `handle = dlopen(argv[0], RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);` the `argv[0]` is the characters used to run the program, not the first command line parameter.   Suggest using `handle = dlopen(argv[1], RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);` so it is using the first parameter.

Comment: Be sure to check the value of `argc` to assure a command line parameter exists,  If accessing `argv[0]` in the dlopen() statement, then trying to find/reload the currently running program.  This is not the correct way to do that.   Rather pass a NULL pointer for the function name.

Answer (score 0):

does the code have the statement:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
```

Are you including the `-ldl` library in the link statement>

if the returned value from `dlopen()` is NULL, then call `dlerror()` to obtain the resulting error message.

NOTE: `dlopen()` loads the library and returns a 'opaque' handle for the library, not a pointer to the actual function.

After a successful call to dlopen() then need to call `dlsym()` to obtain the actual address in memory of the function.

check the returned value from `dlsym()` (!=NULL) to assure the op was successful